# What are all the file types that are supported by the CSS property background-image?

Tags: css, background-image

I cannot find any primary source documentation on what file types are supported by `background-image`. The [W3 specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/colors.html#propdef-background-image) specify "visual" media, but I cannot find a reference to file types.

Comment: The same the browser supports for <img> tag, which varies in every browsers and for which there is no specs restriction.

Comment: Thank you, I have found a list of supported file types for the <img> tag, and subsequently background-image property [on mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably css background depend most formats usage
like : jpg jpeg png and more ...

here in mdn some supported image formats
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EC5c.png)

don't use any wired format